# Avoid looping MySQL query with constrained INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I understand why we should not loop MySQL queries and I am trying to avoid it. I have an array `$names` which contains a list of keywords to insert into `someTable`, with a `UNIQUE` constraint on the MySQL field `name`:

```
mysql> select * from someTable where name='stress';
+-----+--------+
| id  | name   |
+-----+--------+
| 143 | stress |
+-----+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into someTable (name) values ('stress');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'stress' for key 'name'
mysql>
```

I would prefer a query of the following type to avoid a loop:

```
$result = mysql_query("insert into someTable (name) values ('firstName'), ('secondName'), ('thirdName')");
```

However, if any of the names already exist then none of the values get inserted. Furthermore, the value of `$result` will be `FALSE`. **How can I construct a single query to insert the values, which will not fail if any of them exist, and which will return `TRUE` if any of them were inserted?**

I know that I could write a stored procedure for this, but that would just move the loop from PHP to MySQL. Other than bandwidth (not critical as this is on localhost) that doesn't seem to save anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO someTable (name) values ('firstName'), ('secondName'), ('thirdName')
```

If there is a duplicate, it will ignore and continue.

Comment: Thanks, but that will return `TRUE` even if _all_ the names are dupes. I need something that will insert as much as it can, but will return `FALSE` only if all the names were dupes.

Comment: You've gotten me on the right track at least. I might be able to use `mysql_affected_rows` to see if any inserts were made. I'm trying that now.

Comment: Ya, that could work, do a count of how many values you are updating, just compare against.  Did loops beat you as a child?

Comment: Beat me as a child? No, that was my father. But I have seen loops beat other adult devs. In any case, mysql_affected_rows() did what I need after you got me on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: Sheesh, keep it light, glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 3):

use ignore.

example:
`insert ignore into someTable (name)...`

Comment: Haha :) There can be a badge - "fast sender" :)

Comment: Thanks Oleg, for trying. I'll be following you around SO looking for helpful posts to learn from!